# Wpf extended toolkit propertygrid choose editor for all objects of type

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, propertygrid

Right now, I've been specifying what editor the property grid should use by adding attributes to the properties like so:

```
[DisplayName("Background")]
[Editor(typeof(ColorEditor), typeof(ColorEditor))]
public Color Color { get; set; }
```

I don't like this because the Color property is in a library that is separate from the UI project.  It doesn't seem right to add UI attributes to a non-UI library.

How do I specify that the propertygrid should always use a certain editor for a certain type?  I've seen the PropertyGrid documentation, and they give a solution to my problem, but they use custom editors.  I want to be able to use the default editors.